# Prevent uitableview from scrolling after removing last cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableview (style - grouped) which contains more rows than can fit into its frame so you have to scroll to see the last row. When I delete the last row the tableview scrolls its content down so the new last row is at the bottom of the frame (kind of fill the empty space).

How can I prevent a UITableView from scrolling after I delete the last row in it? I want it to keep the empty space and do not scroll automatically.

I have tried to set content insets but it doesn't seem to prevent scrolling unfortunately.

EDIT: My code for removing the row:

```
func removeLastRow() {
    let indexPath = IndexPath.init(row: self.messages.count - 1, section: 0)

    self.messages.removeLast()
    CATransaction.begin()
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock { () -> Void in
       // do stuff, add new rows
    }
    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

Comment: Assuming you *can* delete the row, leaving empty space... What do you want to do next? Should the user be able to scroll the table down, then back up to *keep* the empty space where the row was? Or do you just want it to temporarily be an empty space, and when the user scrolls the "new bottom row" **is** the bottom row?

Comment: @DonMag I want to keep empty space empty. Like an inset. I will eventually remove inset and insert another row. But if I don't - empty space remains empty. So no complex case when user can scroll to bottom and "new last row" has to become "real last".

Comment: Maybe instead of *deleting* the last row, *replace* it with a blank cell?

Answer (score 0):

Retreive the cells size before deleting by calling `tableView:heightForRowAt:` and after deleting, set the vertical content offset of your table view manually to the current vertical content offset, plus the height of the cell.

```
let deletedCellHeight = tableView.heightForRowAt(indexPath)
```

Then:

```
tableView.contentOffset.x += deletedCellHeight
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't seem to work with animations. Now instead of animated scrolling to bottom I get a jerking content, which still jerks to bottom.

Comment: You should use .none as the animation and implement a custom animation block which then can be executed with the content offset setting.

Comment: Hmm, so you propose to fake row deletion animation while maintaining offset? I was hoping to find an easier way :(

Comment: Sadly, UITableView does not provide us an easy way to do this, because the intended behaviour is scrolling up after a cell deletion.